# Row frequency of a data frame ignoring column order in R

Tags: r, frequency

I want to build a frequency table for the rows of a data frame.

I have found how to do it but taking in consideration the order of the columns. I wish to find the frequencies ignoring the columns order.

As an example for:

```
0   A       B     
1   B       A     
2   C       D      
3   D       C     
4   C       D
```

I wish to obtain:

```
A B 2
C D 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmin/pmax` to create the grouping variable and should be more efficient

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   count(V2N = pmin(V2, V3), V3N = pmax(V2, V3))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  V2N   V3N       n
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 A     B         2
#2 C     D         3
```

---

#### Benchmarks

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e6),]
system.time({

df1 %>%
       count(V2N = pmin(V2, V3), V3N = pmax(V2, V3))

 })
#user  system elapsed 
#  1.164   0.043   1.203 


system.time({
df2 <- data.frame(t(apply(df1[-1], 1, sort)))

df2 %>%
   group_by_all() %>%
   summarise(Freq = n())
   
   })
   
#   user  system elapsed 
# 160.357   1.227 161.544
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 0:4, V2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "C"), V3 = c("B", 
  "A", "D", "C", "D")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I do not have enough reputation yet, that is why I have not vote up your suggestions. I am so sorry. But I promise I'll return to do it. Your suggestions have been very useful.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library("tidyverse")

x <- read.table(
  text = "0   A       B
          1   B       A
          2   C       D
          3   D       C
          4   C       D",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x %>%
  # Specify the columns to combine explicitly (here V2 and V3)
  # Then sort each pair and paste it into a single string
  mutate(pair = pmap_chr(list(V2, V3),
                         function(...) paste(sort(c(...)), collapse = " "))) %>%
  count(pair)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   pair      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 A B       2
#> 2 C D       3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First `sort` it row-wise and then group by all the columns and count the number of rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(t(apply(df[-1], 1, sort)))

df1 %>%
   group_by_all() %>%
   summarise(Freq = n())

 #   X1    X2     Freq
 #   <fct> <fct> <int>
 #1  A     B         2
 #2  C     D         3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 0:4, V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), 
.Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```